# What's the source of post Yom Tov Behab

Tags: sources-mekorot

What's the source of post Yom Tov (Sukkos and Pesach) Behab. I see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109119/why-fast-3-days-and-not-more-or-less) the general fasting for rain of Behab but I can't find it for post YT.

Comment: There is a connection to the beginning of the book of Job.

Answer (score 1):

In the Rite and Reason it quotes the Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim 492:1 תענית שני וחמישי ושני אחר המועדים ובו ס"א:
יש נוהגים להתענות שני וחמישי ושני אחר הפסח וכן אחר חג הסוכות וממתינים עד שיעבור כל חדש ניסן ותשרי ואז מתענים: הגה מיד שני וחמישי ושני שאפשר להתענות (ד"ע) ובאשכנז וצרפת נהגו להתענות ועושין אותו כמו תענית צבור לקרות ויחל (טור): Sefaria no translation.

If someone would like to translate please do!

Edit:

Brought in Tractate Kiddushin 81a Tosafos writes: סקבא דשתא ריגלא - פירוש ריעוע של ימות השנה לייחוד ולעבירה כלומר ימות הרגל [שיש] קבוצות אנשים ונשים לשמוע הדרשה ונותנין עין זה על זה וי"א לכך נהגו להתענות לאחר פסח ולאחר סוכות:

This is the weak spot of the year regarding Yichud and immoral behavior. This refers to all the days of Yom-Tov, when groups of men and women gather to listen to the D'rashah (Yarchei Kalah), and they pay attention to one another. Some commentaries explain that this is the reason for the Minhag to fast after Pesach and after Sukkos.

Thanks to Dr Shmuel for posted comment.

Comment: https://dafyomi.co.il/kidushin/tosfos/kd-ts-081.htm !!!

Comment: @Dr Shmuel many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Shulchan Aruch siman 492 mentions Behab, and the mishna beura there says the reason for fasting Behab because of the excitement of Yom Tov. Some say because they is a lot of social gatherings in YT people may fall and sin with speaking frivolous talk with women. So therefore chazal saw fit to institute these fast for repentance and forgiveness.

Comment: Chazal being...? This is not Talmudic.